How many people have died during the wars in Ukraine/Gaza/Lebanon?
How many civilians have been killed during the wars in

Ukraine since 24 February 2022
Gaza since 7 October 2023
Israel  since 7 October 2023
Lebanon since 8 October 2023
Lebanon since 25 September 2024?

Motivation: Iran and America accuse each other of supporting terrorism because one considers Israel as terrorist and the other considers Hezbollah and Hamas.
Russia's attack on Ukraine is known as a war against human rights. A comparison of civilian casualties can be enlightening.

related to https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/84349/how-many-journalists-have-been-killed-in-two-currently-pending-conflicts

My instinct would generally be that as currently written, the question would seem to be two or three questions in one and would be better reformatted as something like "Of the major ongoing conflicts (Gaza, Ukraine, etc.), which has been most lethal for civilians?" That would also prompt people to provide nuance instead of just numbers (e.g. perhaps a larger proportion have died in Gaza even if numerically lower). But your other question does seem to have been reopened after being edited into a very similar format, so I guess the general consensus is that this formulation is focused enough.

I expect this will be a fluid situation where the death tolls will be continually rising, even for a while after each conflict eventually ends, as the dust settles and the bodies can be counted properly. While all three conflicts are still ongoing, though, any answer to this would become outdated very quickly.

Gaza's civilian population has nowhere to run, thanks to "friendly neighbors", unless one takes into account internal displacements in the so called "safe zones". So the comparison is likely to be tilted for that reason. Secondly, war against Hamas/Hezbollah is more like a counter-insurgency, so comparison with Ukraine isn't too well suited [for now]. Comparing with the wars in Iraq, Afghanistan, Syria, Chechnya, or even Sudan would be more suitable.

In fact, even comparing to past wars in Lebanon would be more reasonable.

You'll need to clarify what you mean by "civilian" in your question. I believe that the 'common-sense' definition would exclude many of those being reported as "civilian deaths" by many sources.

Also somewhat related: "give war a chance" and https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/83541/why-does-it-matter-if-the-idf-dropped-a-lot-of-bombs-in-gaza-fast-instead-of-dr

First, it's important to note that there is not consensus on the number of deaths (civilian, soldier, or otherwise) and may never be. The basic problem is that in any armed conflict, the best sources of information are also those with the most incentives to misrepresent casualty numbers. For instance, looking at the Russo-Ukrainian War, Ukraine will naturally want to play up civilian casualities at the hands of Russian soldiers, while Russia will naturally want to downplay them. The best solution is to use relatively independent sources such as the United Nations, but it is still an imperfect solution, because they will likely be relying on information from one or more parties to a given conflict, while (hopefully) keeping the good information and discarding the bad.
That said:

As of July 2024, the United Nations estimated about 11,000 civilian deaths in Ukraine. For completeness, on the other side, at least 100 Russian civilians were thought to have been killed in Western Russia, according to Russian opposition media. Note that the military death toll on both sides is much higher, however.
As of September 2024, the United Nations estimated about 40,000 deaths in Gaza, without breaking them down by civilian status. Although this data does rely on the Gaza Health Ministry, it is likely the best source available under the circumstances; unfortunately, the Israeli government does not seem particularly interested in providing estimates for civilian deaths in Gaza, rather providing estimates of Hamas soldiers killed that have been criticized for potentially employing overly broad criteria or simply assuming Hamas membership or militant status.  For completeness, on the other side, a few dozen Israeli civilians have been killed in connection with the ongoing conflict, not counting the 800 or so estimated to have been killed in the October 7 attacks.
For the conflict between Israel and Hezbollah (and now, in Lebanon in general), Wikipedia lists various estimates, arriving at a total of about 1800 deaths in Lebanon, with 800 since the escalation this month. How many are civilians is unclear, though it is likely the majority. On the other side, it estimates a few dozen Israel civilian casualties, though since the Times of Israel is its only source, that must be taken with a grain of salt.

In at least the first two cases, the actual death toll is estimated to be substantially higher. These are likely conservative estimates.
With those numbers given, a major caveat is that comparing absolute numbers here is very fraught. To start with, population sizes: the Gaza Strip has a population over around 2 million, Lebanon has a population of around 5 million, and Ukraine has a population of around 40 million. As such, for instance, if all those numbers given previously were completely correct, the impact to date on the population in the Gaza Strip would be not about four times as high, but about 80 times as high. Just as ten murders per year in a small town of 100 are a decimation, but 10 murders per year in New York would be a paradise, it's not the same in terms of the risk to any given person or the overall societal impact to have the same death toll in countries with widely varying population sizes.
Yet another major caveat is that the wars have been ongoing for different time periods: over two years for the Russo-Ukrainian War, a little under one year in the case of the Gaza Strip, and arguably only a few weeks in the case of the invasion of Lebanon (or less). Most notably, it would be a mistake to look at the recent escalation in Lebanon, ongoing for a few weeks, and to declare it to be much less dangerous than the war in Gaza or that in Ukraine, since the rate of deaths is still high and the impact will likely rapidly climb.
A final reservation is that one cannot necessarily use these numbers in isolation to infer much about the relative willingness of the different parties to countenance or particularly seek civilian casualties (other than to note that it is clearly substantially different from zero in all cases), since a lower rate of civilian casualties may represent many factors, such as ease of escape, the strength of the opposing force, the types of weapons being used, the weather, and so forth.
And while it might be editorializing slightly, I would like to conclude this answer by discouraging people from trying to use these numbers to determine which of these wars is "the best" or "the worst." As understood in international law and by most people, human rights do not admit degrees, by which some low level of violations is acceptable; rather, even avoidably killing one civilian is a human rights violation.

One could also add that in the Ukraine war the distinction between soldiers and civilians is fairly clear in most cases and both sides generally obey rules of war, in consequence most of the deaths are among soldiers and not among civilians. In Gaza on the other hand the distinction soldier/civilian is much less clear, fighting is not only done by soldiers and a large part of the total deaths is among civilians.

There's also the matter of population density; the Gaza Strip was one of the most densely populated areas on Earth even before Israel began ordering its entire population to evacuate certain areas. If you were to hypothetically throw a missile at a random area of Ukraine, and a second identical missile at a random area of Gaza, the likelihood of the Gaza missile hitting an area populated by civilians would be much higher.

Does the "Gaza Ministry of Health" or even the Lebanese equivalent report Hamas or Hezbollah combatant deaths as non-civilian?

"Although this data does rely on the Gaza Health Ministry, it is likely the best source available under the circumstances" - VS - "since the Times of Israel is its only source, that must be taken with a grain of salt". Wow! Hamas Health Ministry is the "best available source", but Israeli non-state unregulated free media, where everyone can say whatever they wish, "must be taken with a grain of salt". Do you know of any news outlet, in any free country, that can make up dozens of deaths, without facing backlash from the public?

@Jacob3 -  A relatively unbiased person would likely note that my treatment of these two sources is essentially similar: pointing out their limitations, but using them anyway because there is nothing better. You do not strike me as unbiased.

@IVFcomesfromthetip - They do not distinguish between the two, indeed, and neither does the United Nations in the source that I cited. I should have written that the United Nations reported 40,000 deaths without distinguishing civilian status, which I have now edited to fix. Regardless, no matter how much I point out that any numbers should be taken as uncertain because of the incentives of various sources to distort the data or their interpretation thereof, certain partisans will always complain.

@Obie2.0, That's exactly the problem, that your answer is "unbiased" between a fanatic terror organization, for whom lying is the most insignificant moral transgression, and a reputable liberal news outlet.

@Jacob3 - As I said. I don't generally consider news sources from within one of the parties to a conflict to be unbiased sources. There are those who would be bothered that I cited their numbers at all; there are those who are bothered that I encourage people to treat information from within countries party to a conflict with caution when they happen to be from or be partial to one of those parties. All such individuals will likely be dissatisfied with my approach here.

@Jacob3 Fox News, for example. But it also happens with israeli newspapers. I do think Obie2.0 should distinguish between sources from the Gaza Health Ministery and those from Israeli sources, as in, the former has been proven time and again quite reliable, while the latter had been caught lying many times. Quoting a US presidents famously known for his veracity, "there are very fine people of both sides of this issue".

@Rekesoft - As I said, people who want their preferred sources to be reported uncritically will probably be disappointed with this answer. I don't believe that any sources from within a party to a conflict can be taken uncritically for a wide variety of reasons.
